# Hide parameters from @Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code

```
<a href="@Url.Action(" Edicao ", "EdicaoListaVerificacao ", new { idFormulario = m.Id })" title="Editar" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true" />
```

Where 'Edit' is my action and 'FunctionEdit' is my Controller. My action needs a parameter and I passed it building a 'instance'. How the property needs. The problem is that the URL can be altered and the user can access things that they can't.

Comment: You can never hide your URLs - nor should you. You should verify, instead, inside the Edicao action method that the user has permission to view the Formulario with the specified Id.

Comment: @bzlm You should turn that into an answer.

Comment: @bzlm Can I block the users to edit the URL?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. Tks for your tip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can never hide your URLs - nor should you. You should verify, instead, inside the `Edicao` action method that the user has permission to view the *Formulario* with the specified *Id*.

In all web applications, you have to assume that the URLs users try to retrieve can be absolutely anything - and that some users will attempt to edit URLs to get at hidden content. ASP.NET has built-in authentication and authorization mechanisms that you should use.

If you're just looking for a simple way to make a URL that's impossible to *guess*, without forcing users to log on, you have to use something more complicated than a numeric ID, like a GUID.

And if at any point you are tempted by roll-your-own solutions such as URL referrer checking or verifying cookies, remember that easier-to-use solutions are most likely built into ASP.NET already.

Comment: Excellent idea @bzlm, but I'm fixing an old program that have more than one million of registers. When I search about GUID I saw that he returns a string and my **idFormulario = m.Id**  is a Auto Increment from Mysql. I can't change it.

Comment: @AnessOllemAzuos Then implement a check in your action method to make sure the user is allowed to access that ID, as bzlm suggested.

Comment: @AnessOllemAzuos, the more context you provide on questions, the more useful answers you will get. :)

Answer (score -6):

That's it! Thank you, guys. I found a way to implement a check in my action. With *Request.UrlReferrer*.

```
 public ActionResult Edicao(int idFormulario)
        {
            Uri url = Request.UrlReferrer;

            if (url != null)
            {

               DO ALL THINGS YOU HAVE TO

            }
            else
            {
                RETURN TO INDEX
            }

        }
```

The *Request.UrlReferrer* returns me the URL if it comes from my request. If not returns *null*. Than I just build an *if block* ;). Thank you guys!

Comment: This is not secure. URL referrer can be faked. Read what bzlm and I are telling you. If you want to make sure a user is allowed to access it, then you must implement a check on the ID.

Comment: I don't know how to do this. Can u explain me? Do u mean using session?

Comment: No, I don't mean using Session. I mean make a call to your database and verify that the user is supposed to have access to that item.

Comment: I already did this. My big problem is not the page acess, coz like u sad I did the permission request. My problem is one of the parameters be changed by an user. For exemple: my _URL_ is _http://localhost:65305/EdicaoListaVerificacao/Edicao?idFormulario=2_ the users can change the number 2 for 3 and edit form 3. But form 3 can't be edited coz was already published. Did u understand? Sorry if I was no so clear and thanks for your atention.

Comment: **Verify** the parameters. Make sure they make sense. If form 3 was already published and the user is trying to access the edit page, then **verify** that. `if (form3.State == "published") {Response.Redirect("~/NotAllowed.html");}` or something along those lines. The point is, you can't prevent people from changing the query string variables or changing the URL referrer, you can only control what you present to them based on who they are and what they want to access.